# How to get url and port from app.js using node/express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get the value of the url from app.js so I can assign it to app.locals

an use it on the templates. How do I do it from app.js ? I am using express js

generator. so my main file is the app.js. I just want to get the current

url/domain and put it on app.locals, like a define variable.

```
app.locals = {
    socket_io_host: 'http://localhost:3001',
    socket_io_port: "3001",
};
```

Comment: Not clear what are you asking. What is the code in app.js?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you want the IP address of the server on which you have hosted the application. If this is the case then please use the following module:
[Node IP](https://github.com/indutny/node-ip)

Other case is if you want the IP address of the requesting client then you can use the following code:

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] //IF APP IS BEHIND PROXY
req.connection.remoteAddress //IF APP IS NOT BEHIND PROXY
```